# How to delete from a table with a common column without deleting everything from that column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a table that I just inserted 11 entries into. I now want to delete them. They carry a common column of tot_cred = 0 but there are others in that column with tot_cred = 0 as well. The other columns are ID, name and dept_name. Sorry for the lack of info, I'm new to this. The point is to see if there is one piece of code that can do this instead of doing it the "long" way.

Is there a way to delete these with one query or do I have to do it one by one?

Comment: what other common features those 11 entries have?

Comment: There are ELEVEN of them, it took more time to write this question then to delete them by hand, one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. The point is to execute it with one statement instead of 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only similarity they have is tot_cred = 0, and there are other items that have that same value, then you're probably out of luck.

Do you have other columns like a Date?

More information of your columns would be helpful.

Comment: The other columns are ID, name and dept_name. Sorry for the lack of info, I'm new to this. The point is to see if there is one piece of code that can do this instead of doing it the "long" way.

Comment: Long story short, you should just delete them by hand.  Depending on what your "Date" field has in it, you could do something like "select * from [table] where tot_Cred = 0 AND Date > [whatever date], if that's a kind of "Creation date".